# Optimize bash script that concatenates output

Tags: bash, shell, posix, sh

I am trying to optimize my script that loops through a folder and extracts only the part of a file name before a date and the header of the file and outputs it into a different file using a delimiter. I feel the script is robust and I want to refactor it. If there is also a better way, please tell me.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script variables
FOLDER=path/to/folder
LOG_FILE=path/to/logfile.csv

# Getting the pattern and  header of files from FOLDER
for file in `ls $FOLDER/*.csv`
do
    echo -n $(basename "$file") 2>&1 | sed -r 's/(.*)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv/\1/'  | tee -a $LOG_FILE
    echo -n "|" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
    cat $file | head -1 | tee -a $LOG_FILE

done #> $LOG_FILE
```

Answer (score 9):

- `do ... done` is a compound command; every subcommand shares the file descriptors; so `tee`ing the the loop has the same effect as `tee`ing each subcommand.
- Two subsequent invocations of `echo` can be combined together.
- `cat $file` is a dreaded UUOC.
- A `basename` invocation can be avoided by changing directory to `$FOLDER`.
- `ls` is absolutely unnecessary. The shell already globbed the `*.csv`.

Summing up,

```
    chdir "$FOLDER"
    for file in *.csv; do
        echo -n "$file" "|" | sed -r ...
        head -1 "$file"
    done | tee $LOGFILE
```

does the same job.

Comment: Thanks vnp. It is very compact and does the same job. Just one modification chdir should be cd.

Comment: Don't forget to leave in the `-a` argument to `tail`, assuming you want to append to the log instead of overwriting it.

Comment: and I had to google UUOC (though the first hit was right).  For others: it means "useless uses of cat"

Comment: You can also lose the `sed` with a `[[ $file =~ (.*)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.csv ]] && echo -n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Answer (score 2):

That sed pattern seems rather overly specific for a part of the filename you want to dump (unless there are other `_#_#-#.#.csv` filename endings that you *do* want to keep).

If you just want to dump from the second to last `_` in the file then you can use

```
awk -F _ -v OFS=_ 'NF-=2' <<<"$file"
```

or

```
echo "$file" | awk -F _ -v OFS=_ 'NF-=2'
```

Alternatively I think one of these might do what is desired as well in a single command.

```
awk --re-interval '{len=split(FILENAME, f, "/"); sub(/_[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv$/, "", f[len]); printf f[len] "|"; print; nextfile}' /path/to/folder/*.csv
```

Or if the regex is over-specified (as per my comment on the OP) then perhaps:

```
awk '{len=split(FILENAME, f, "/"); sub(/_[^_]+_[^_]+.csv$/, "", f[len]); printf f[len] "|"; print; nextfile}' /path/to/folder/*.csv
```